# How to expire Action Cache when underlying model is updated in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-6, action-caching

I am using Action Caching which seems to work OK with Rails 6.

The issue is how to expire the cache when the underlying model is updated?

According to [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#action-caching)

> See the actionpack-action_caching gem. See DHH's key-based cache expiration overview for the newly-preferred method.

According to the [Action Caching gem issue](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching/issues/53), using a Rails Observer to sweep the cache would work.

https://github.com/rails/rails-observers#action-controller-sweeper

But [Rails Observer](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/issues) does not seem to work with Rails 6.

So, how to expire the cache with an `after_save` callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass in your own cache_path to expire the key. You still need to fetch some record to calculate it though.

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_record

  caches_action :show, expires_in: 1.hour, cache_path: ->(_) { show_cache_key }

  def show; end

  private

  def set_record
    @record = Record.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show_cache_key
    @record.cache_key
  end
end
```

[Doing cache invalidation by hand is an incredibly frustrating and error-prone process](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) so I would avoid invalidating keys in an `after_step` and use key based expiration instead.

Comment: Thank you. `@record.cache_key` was very helpful.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Used `puts Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).keys` to see what was going on.

Comment: Just use `cache_path: -> { @record.cache_key }` instead of `cache_path: ->(_) { show_cache_key }`. You don't need method `show_cache_key` in that case